# galleria image gallery

Tags: jquery, css, galleria

hello friends i am using this galleria gallery link to display images on my college website..
but i m not able to fix one thing. when the size of the image changes it changes the display Div's size according to the size of the image.I want it to be fixed Div what ever be the size of the image is[link text](http://www.monc.se/kitchen/146/galleria-a-javascript-image-gallery)

Can any body tell him whats the problm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in the demo, the div that the picture sits in is a set height and width. The pictures that are displayed are all the same set width and height (the same width and height as the containing div). In order for you to have the same look as the demo, you will have to make your images and thumbnails a uniform height and width.

Comment: They cropped their images to the same size. You could declare the image size in a class:<br/><br/>

.imgSize
{
width:550px;
height:350px;
}
<br/><br/>
The problem with that is resizing will throw off the aspect ratio of the picture, making it look strecthed or squeezed.

It looks as if what the person did in the demo was custom make their images for the div. So it's possible that there's more to the picture than what is displayed, but they've cut those parts out to make the display neater.